# How to join these 2 tables by date with ORM

Tags: python, django, postgresql, orm

I have two querysets -

```
A = Bids.objects.filter(*args,**kwargs).annotate(highest_priority=Case(*[
When(data_source=data_source, then Value(i))
for i, data_source in enumerate(data_source_order_list)
],
.order_by(
"date",
"highest_priority"
))

B= A.values("date").annotate(Min("highest_priority)).order_by("date")
```

First query give me all objects with selected time range with proper data sources and values. Through highest_priority i set which item should be selected. All items have additional data.

Second query gives me grouped by information about items in every date. In second query i do not have important values like price etc. So i assume i have to join these two tables and filter out where a.highest_priority = b.highest priority. Because in this case i will get queryset with objects and only one item per date.

I have tried using distinct - not working with .first()/.last(). Annotates gives me dict by grouped by, and grouping by only date cutting a lot of important data, but i have to group by only date...

Tables looks like that

A
[image: A]

B
[image: B]

How to join them? Because when i join them i could easily filter highest_prio with highest_prio and get my date with only one database shot. I want to use ORM, because i could just distinct and put it on the list and i do not want to hammer base with connecting multiple queries through date.

Answer (score 0):

Look if this sugestion works :

```
 SELECT *  , (to_char(a.date, 'YYYYMMDD')::integer)*highest_priority AS prioritycalc;
FROM table A 
JOIN table B ON (to_char(a.date, 'YYYYMMDD')::integer)*highest_priority = (to_char(b.date, 'YYYYMMDD')::integer)*highest_priority 
ORDER BY prioritycalc DESC;
```